# Join table and display

Tags: mysql, listview, yii2

I am using the Yii PHP framework, trying to display user_comment and user_reply from two tables who both have a column named comment_id.

This is the comment table

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `byy` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `user_comment` varchar(900) NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `up` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `down` bigint(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is the reply table

```
CREATE TABLE `reply` (
  `reply_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` int(19) NOT NULL,
  `byy` varchar(29) NOT NULL,
  `user_reply` varchar(29) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `up` varchar(29) NOT NULL,
  `down` varchar(29) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to display user_comment and user_reply in a list view format, sorted according to the comment_id. I am having problems with that.

```
  <?php
    $querys = new Query;
    $querys->select([
        'comment.user_comment', 
        'reply.user_reply']
        )  
      ->from('comment')
      ->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'reply',
            'reply.comment_id =comment.comment_id') ; 
     $command = $querys->createCommand();
    $data = $command->queryAll(); 

    $queryd = new Query;
    $queryd->select([
        'comment.user_comment', 
        'reply.user_reply']
        )  
      ->from('comment')
      ->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'reply',
            'reply.comment_id =comment.comment_id')    
      ->LIMIT(5); 
     $command = $queryd->createCommand();
    $data = $command->queryAll();  


 foreach ($data as $detail) {
        $dataArr[] = array(
            'user_reply' => $detail['user_reply']
        );
      }
          $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $dataArr,
                'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
                ],
                'sort' => [
                    'attributes' => ['comment_created_at'],
                ],
            ]);
          echo ListView::widget([
             'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
             'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'comment-item'],
             'itemView' => 'adapter',

        ]);
    ?>
```

Adapter class

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;

//var_dump($model);exit;
?>

              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            <section>

            <?php echo $model['user_reply']; ?>


            </section>
          </div>
```

I am getting this error:

> Getting unknown property: Undefined index: user_reply

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which class of the object `$detail`? Look carefully into that class, do you have `user_reply` property in this class? If not, please update your model using *Gii generator*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($data as $detail) {
        $dataArr[] = array(
            'user_reply' => $detail['reply.user_reply']
        );
      }
```

or use alias

```
$queryd = new Query;
$queryd->select('comment.user_comment as user_comment, 
                reply.user_reply as user_reply')  
->from('comment')
->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'reply',
    'reply.comment_id =comment.comment_id')    
 ->LIMIT(5); 
 $command = $queryd->createCommand();
 $data = $command->queryAll();  

 foreach ($data as $detail) {
        $dataArr[] = array(
            'user_reply' => $detail['user_reply']
        );
      }
```

and for dataProvider you must remeber there is a models collection then

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
    <section>

      <?php  
          foreach($models as $model){
               //echo $model['user_reply']; 
                echo $model->user_reply; 
          }
        ?>

     </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: not working still Getting unknown property: yii\db\Connection::user_reply

Comment: i updated my question how do i makei display in adapter

Comment: I have update the answer for dataProvider.. if useful please rate my answer as useful too

Comment: getting syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101625/discussion-between-arinze-and-scaisedge).

Comment: i am getting Illegal string offset 'user_reply'